# Inheritance from template class with a type defined in the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to inherit from a template class with a type defined in the derived class. I dont want to use composition because if I do so, I have to give public access to the vector or write some methods for each object in order to interact with the vector the way I want to.

Is there any way to make this code work ?

(Ok I just have to declare my struct before the class like in 1) commented example, but I am interested to know is there some hack to do it like this...)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Interface
{
public:
   virtual void populate() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Series : Interface
{
public:
   T methodIwantToWriteOnce(int i) const { return mVec[i]; }

protected:
   std::vector<T> mVec;
};

class SeriesInt : public Series<int>
{
public:
   virtual void populate() override { mVec.push_back(42); }
};



/* 1) Working solution but outside the class */
// struct Coord
// {
//    double x = 0.0;
//    double y = 0.0;
// };
// class SeriesCoord : public Series<Coord>
// {
// public:
//    virtual void populate() override { mVec.push_back({42.0, 42.0}); }
// };


/* 2) Impossible solution ? */
// Forward declaration
class SeriesCoord;
struct SeriesCoord::Coord; //useless I know but you see the idea

class SeriesCoord : public Series<SeriesCoord::Coord>
{
public:
   struct Coord
   {
      double x = 0.0;
      double y = 0.0;
   };
   virtual void populate() override { mVec.push_back({42.0, 42.0}); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   SeriesInt s1;
   s1.populate();
   std::cout << s1.methodIwantToWriteOnce(0) << std::endl;

   SeriesCoord s2;
   s2.populate();
   std::cout << s2.methodIwantToWriteOnce(0).x << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you declare `Coord` outside `SeriesCoord`? (you might still add alias...)

Comment: @Jarod42 thx, but like I said "I just have to declare my struct before the class, but I am interesting to know is there some hack to do it like this.."

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, any type that will be defined in the derived type will be incomplete at the moment you try to instantiate the base class with it. CRTP won't help here either.